# Why are unitary groups ramified at half the places?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field, reductive-groups

I would like to understand precisely the structure of local unitary groups. A property that seems to appear in many places and which I do not understand is that a unitary group is ramified at half the places.

So let $F$ be a global non-archimedean number field, $E$ a quadratic extension of $F$, and $U$ a unitary group (*i.e.* the group of automorphism preserving a n hermitian form on $E$), say of rank $n$ (*i.e.* the hermitian form is on a squared $n$-dimensional vector space).

What can be said for the local groups, that is for the $U_v$ where $v$ goes through the places of $F$? More precisely:

- is there only a finite number of possibility for $U_v$?
- why "half" of the $U_v$ are "unramified", in the sense that $U_v \cong \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$?

Thanks in advance !